# Context Switching with kernel level threads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Does Context switching becomes faster or slower with kernel supported threads as compared to user level threads.?

Comment: Don't think it matters much - AFAIK, nobody uses user level threads.

Comment: Which OS? Which user thread library? In which situation?

Comment: The cost of a context switch is dominated by the time required to reload the various processor caches.  Which depends on what thread is switched to.  Which is entirely unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally**, it does not matter. Process scheduler would perform the same set of operation in both the cases. The thread that is being swapped out or the thread that is being swapped in, could be user or kernel thread. This would not impact the time it takes to perform context switch. Context switch is the process of saving the current state of running process(various register values and other data structure,eg. PCB) and restoring the saved state of a  process(restoring various register values and other data structure,eg. PCB). All the storing and retrieving of the data is in the kernel space.

Context switch does not involve choosing the next process/thread to execute, that is the job of the process scheduler.